# Whenever I try to join a game, it says, "Could not join due to join script failure."

Tags: technical-issues, roblox

I try to to join a server that my friend is in, but when the Roblox Gameplay window pops up, it shows a message that says:

> Could Not Join Due To Join Script Failure

There is nothing wrong with my internet connection or anything else. I checked for solutions but none work. I don't know what the error meant by "Join Script Failure". Could the script not function properly?

It works on my other friends, but coinicidentaly it happens to some friends who are playing certain games such as Murder Mystery 2. But when a I join a friend who is playing a different game such as the Natural Disasters game, I'm successful. But is there any way to fix this issue?

I have tried this many times, so please don't tell me to try it gain for a second time unless there is something I must do between that.

Comment: Your problem stems from a long-running issue to do with Mark-up and Revison-of-Code. It may be that your System Version is incompatible with _whatever_ goes on in that server, or the Developer left some groups of computers out. Send a screenshot of the incident to the developer and they'll try to whip-up a solution.

Comment: This happens to me many times, but I think it's to do with the game, not you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem usually occurs when a bug in the script has been reached. 
It is the issue of the Developer, not you. I suggest you to open the dev console ingame (F9) and send a screenshot of it to the dev.

Are your friends VIPs? It could also be that you tried to follow your friend in a VIP server.

Comment: No, it isn't a VIP Server, but thanks for the answer. I'll return after I do this.

Answer (score 1):

So this happened to me before and I don't know if I can take any chances on doing this so but when this happens have you ever tried restarting your computer and then going back to Roblox or logging out of your account and logging back in to join the game you wanted to play? This happens to me a lot, so try that. If it doesn't work then I do not know what to do next so try that :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the issue before as well. 
Here's a list of possibilities.

- Program bugs
- VIP servers
- You've been banned from the game (highly unlikely)

Hitting this issue is uncontrollable, but the developer(s) will probably solve the issue soon after you find it. It's no good having a buggy game.
I myself would just wait for a day or play another game. The game will probably be fixed by then.